# AWS instance to run NVIDIA Omniverse Audio2Face

Tags: amazon-web-services, nvidia, omniverse

I want to try [NVIDIA Omniverse Audio2Face](https://docs.omniverse.nvidia.com/audio2face/latest/common/technical-requirements.html?highlight=requirements). I don't have an RTX GPU, so I want to run it on the cloud.

The requirements, shown in a splash screen of Audio2Face, are:

> Minimum:
>
> CPU: Intel Core i7 (7th Generation); AMD Ryzen 5
>
> CPU cores: 4
>
> RAM: 16GB
>
> Storage: 50GB SSD
>
> VRAM: 8GB
>
> GPU: Any RTX GPU

> Recommended
>
> CPU: Intel Core i7 (9th Generation); AMD Ryzen 7
>
> CPU Cores: 8
>
> RAM: 32GB
>
> Storage: 500GB SSD
>
> VRAM: 10GB
>
> GPU: GeForce RTX 3070 NVIDIA RTX A4000

[image: Omniverse splash screen]

I can't seem to find instances that use those specific CPUs and GPUs. I tried on a `g3.8xlarge`, whose [page](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/g3/) mentions:

> vCPUs based on custom 2.7 GHz Intel Xeon E5 2686 v4 processors ... NVIDIA Tesla M60 GPUs

I set up that machine, install Remote Desktop Protocol, install Omniverse and Audio2Face. I launch it, the button changes to "Launching" and after a few seconds goes back to "Launch." I look at the logs (located at Profile Settings), but I don't see any mention of "failure", "fail" or "error". A thread on the [NVIDIA Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/is-it-possible-to-run-audio2face-on-cloud/259492) from 6 months ago asks about running it on the cloud, with no answers. So I'm not sure:

- if the instance I set doesn't meet the requirements and I should try a different one
- if it does meet the requirements but running Audio2Face on the cloud requires a dedicated host rather than a virtual machine
- if running Audio2Face on the cloud is just not possible.

How can I find an AWS instance type that meets the minimum or recommended requirements and run Omniverse Audio2Face on the cloud?